# How to prevent the submit button from reloading the page, while keeping default form warnings?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, button, page-refresh

I have a simple form to get a table's row/column numbers, with a button  `type = "submit"` that reloads the page onClick .

I want to keep the warnings when the user enters an invalid value, since the inputs have a maximum/minimum number required, which is not possible with the `return false;` in the end of the onClick method, or `event.preventDefault();`

Any ideas how to do that?

This code is in JSX:

```html
<form id="table_form">
   <label>how many rows ?</label>
   <input
     type="number"
     name="rows"
     min={min_tablerows}
     max={max_tablerows}
     required
     value={tablerows}
     onChange={onChangeHandeler} />
   <label>how many columns ?</label>
   <input
     type="number"
     name="columns"
     min={min_tablecolumns}
     required
     value={tablecolumns}
     onChange={onChangeHandeler} />
   <button
     type="submit"
     form="table_form"
     onClick={onClickHandeler}>
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What about simply removing `type="submit"` ?

Comment: it doesn't reload the page , but the warnings are still missing if i enter an invalid value .

Comment: try calling your validator after preventDefault? if all valid, use js to submit form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to keep the default html warnings if I understand your question well. I would like to suggest the following:

1. Firstly, you don't need to attach `onClick` event handler for the `button` because a `button` in an HTML `form` or with the type `submit` by default submits to the form it is contained.
2. You can attach `onSubmit` event handler to the main form and in its callback function prevent the default behaviour.
3. With this, html5 will handle any errors and prevent the form from even submitting in the first place. When it doesn't find any error, it will run the callback function attached to the form's event handler.

So your code might be as follows:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// Do what you like here

e.target.submit(); // if you want to submit the forms
}

<form id="table_form" onSubmit={this.handleSumbit.bind(this)}>
   <label>how many rows ?</label>
   <input
     type="number"
     name="rows"
     min={min_tablerows}
     max={max_tablerows}
     required
     value={tablerows}
     onChange={onChangeHandeler} />
   <label>how many columns ?</label>
   <input
     type="number"
     name="columns"
     min={min_tablecolumns}
     required
     value={tablecolumns}
     onChange={onChangeHandeler} />
   <button
     type="submit">
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
   </button>
</form>
```